# How To Share object state across all Azure Function Instances

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a C# Azure Function App (consumption plan) which scales dynamically i.e new instances are added depending on the load, now we have an object which needs to be used across all instances of this Azure Function, as the object is complex (has delegates) I cannot serialize to put on an external cache so that all instances can access it from there, please suggest the best way to handle this scenario.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking. Before it gets voted down to close, provide more details.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Function instances are running on different servers, they do not share the same memory, so there is no way for all of them to access a single .NET object without remote calls (and thus serialization).

Answer (score 3):

There's something fundamentally contradictory in your question: you can't have both a) a function that scales to many machines; b) all instances sharing in-memory objects as if they were running on a single machine. 
It goes the other way too: serverless means that if nobody is using your function, all infrastructure can be shut down (hence saving you money) - but that implicitly means you'd lose your in-memory state and need to be able to serialize it.

Minimize the shared state, make it serializable (there are patterns for dealing with things like delegates [1]),  and use external storage (Azure Storage, or a cache like Redis).

[1] For delegates, one trick is to maintain a dictionary of handles to delegates, and then serialize the handle. Similarly, for polymorphism, you might serialize the type name.

Comment: One thing which I believe happens internally is that all the function instances are managed by a external process a sort of Orchestrator, which has access to all the instances is there a way this external process supports inter instance state sharing...

Comment: @Akhil - there are several external processes involved here to monitor for triggers, bring up the machine, etc and ultimately lead to invoking the function. But that's largely irrelevant. There is still no built-in state sharing.