# can you store a value in a global dictionary in a Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have created an azure function with 2 HTTP triggers, now the issue I am facing is I need to store a value from the first HTTP trigger inside a dictionary like the one below

```
static Dictionary<int, TargetRequest> Target = new Dictionary<int, TargetRequest>();
```

This is inside my function class but outside the trigger.
Now after another HTTP trigger I need to retrieve that value from the dictionary and use it, but only after it's received a trigger. Being completely new to Azure I'm not sure if the values in that dictionary stay or not as it seems to work on localhost but not when deployed to Azure. If they don't, what is another way to go about this. Is using an Azure Queue Storage the way to store this value or is there another way to go about this?

Ps: TargetRequest is a c# class, if that makes any difference.

Cheers

Comment: Azure function is serverless. You have some code to be executed. It takes some data from request or storage (bus, database blob queue etc.). Maybe it is possible but don't do it.

Comment: Yeah I feared that'd be the case, so would hosting that server application in something like IIS be the way to go then as it needs to be publicly accessed or is there another non serverless solution in Azure or AWS?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220604/how-to-share-object-state-across-all-azure-function-instances.

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp

Comment: If your function is always singleton, there should be no problem to getting the static dictionary from the first Trigger. If the singleton operation cannot be guaranteed, you can save the data externally, such as queue or temporary files etc.

Comment: I would suggest to go for a persistent storage like Azure Table which is cheap and should already being created with your function app.

Comment: Can you post your code? What do you mean by `This is inside my function class but outside the trigger.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) that Perkins mentioned (which come with it's own complexity and [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints) that you need to understand), you need to imagine each instance of your Function running on a new different laptop every time it runs. To underline, one run = a new/different laptop. You can not ever rely on "instance reuse", i.e. same laptop being used twice in two different runs. This is of course purely from design point of view.

Two options:

1. Using [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp)
2. Build your own cache using appropriate service. Storage Q is not an appropriate choice. Better examples are [Redis](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/), any transactional DB, ADLS, etc. See some [architectural guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching) that Azure provides around caching. This is a common problem in SaaS/Cloud world.

Answer (score -3):

If you set the function to singleton mode, you should be able to get the static dictionary of Function1 in Function2.

If your Function is not in singleton mode, you can save the data externally, such as queue or temporary files.

Comment: Just wondering if you've tested this on a high traffic environment where the server scales up and creates multiple instances of the function?

Comment: Even if this somehow worked when you tested in the cloud, serverless functions are not guaranteed to run in the same (virtual) server, nor in same memory space, nor are they guaranteed to persist over multiple invocations.  This is a very bad idea and will not scale and ultimately will fail.

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks, I just do a simple test. Will edit.

Comment: @zolty13 I have already change the answer before.